# OutOfMemory exception when loading UI through bitmaps

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

I tried loading my UI by using bitmaps getting an OutOfMemory exception. I have used PNG's previously, then I converted them to GIFs hoping to reduce memory usage by loading the bitmaps. The total of the images is 291kb (when using PNGs it was about 2.2mb).

I am using this code using inSampleSize to load the images if the images are a lot bigger than the screen size:

```
public void loadViewImage(View view, int drawableID) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableID, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableID, options)));
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    while (height / inSampleSize > reqHeight || width / inSampleSize > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

The image is then loaded through:

```
final RelativeLayout backgroundLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
backgroundLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            loadViewImage(backgroundLayout, R.drawable.background);
        }
    });
```

This app works on a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge but not on an LG G2. When using inSampleSize 2 it does, but I'm wondering how these 291kb images use so much memory.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all there's a lot more easier way to do this use `Picasso` for android or if you still want to get it on your own way use all the heavy logics to Bitmap Scaling and calculation away from UI thread clue `AsyncTask`

Comment: *291kb images* no, they are not taking such size when they are loaded as Bitmap ... once again: **THE FILE SIZE DOESN'T MATTER**

Comment: `The total of the images is 291kb `. Whats more relevant is the resolution of the images. As memory use of bitmaps depends on the resolution. Now you do not have the resolution under control if you use BitmapFactory.decodeResource() as the bitmap will be adapted to the screan. You could better decode from a normal input stream.

Comment: The resolution of the images is big enough to fit on a 1440x2560 screen. This means the inSampleSize conversion will return 1 on a phone with a screen size more than half of the original image size. Also, I thought the bitmap would not be loaded in the memory when using BitmapFactory.decodeResource() when setting inJustDecodeBounds to true. I have found no other way than with the code provided to use bitmaps to build the UI. Is there any other way? I will look into Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

THe people telling you size doesn't matter are a bit off.  The filesize doesn't matter.  Nor does GIF vs JPG, vs PNG.  What does matter is image size in pixels.  A Bitmap object is uncompressed, whereas the files are compressed.  That means it takes 4 bytes per pixel (plus some overhead which is small enough to be ignored).  So a 1440x2560 image is about 3.7 million pixels-  or about 15MB.  Each one takes up that much memory.  Scaling it will take more-  you have to decode at least part of the original to scale it (it may take up to the sum of the two individual sizes).

Generally when you see OOM errors the problem is how you use memory throughout your code, not just in one place.  The best way to check that is via heap profiling looking for run away object creation/retention.  Although a very large image (such as a picture from a 12Mpixel camera common on new devices) may cause a lot of problems in scaling-  the image alone will take 50MB.  Unless you're loading a lot of full screen images, this shouldn't be a problem.  If you are, you should probably recycle them when done by hand.  If you have a lot of activities with layouts like this and may have a deep stack, you may want to consider getting rid of the images in onPause and reloading in onResume to save memory.